# learn a threshold from labels and discrimination values?

Tags: python, r, algorithm

I have a set of `{(v_i, c_i), i=1,..., n}`, where `v_i in R` and `c_i in {-1, 0, 1}` are the discrimination value  and  label of the i-th training example.

I would like to learn a threshold `t` so that the training error is the minimum when I declare the i-th example has label `-1` if `v_i < t`, `0` if `v_i=t`, and `1` if `v_i>t`.

How can I learn the threshold `t` from `{(v_i, c_i), i=1,..., n}`, and what is an efficient algorithm for that?

I am implementing that in Python, although I also hope to know how to implement that in  R efficiently.

Thanks!

Btw, why SO doesn't support LaTeX for math expressions? (I changed them to be code instead).

Answer (score 1):

Sort the points, group them by value, and try all <=2n+1 thresholds that classify differently (<=n+1 gaps between distinct data values including the sentinels +-infinity and <=n distinct data values). The latter step is linear-time if you try thresholds lesser to greater and keep track of how many points are misclassified in each way.

Comment: thanks, David. If the discrimation scores are floats, not integers, how can I check the equality case (i.e. classify to class 0)

Comment: @Tim This answer uses only the ordering properties of the scores. Is the problem that the equality test should be fuzzy?

Comment: there is no restriction or something special about the problem.

Comment: @Tim As you sweep the threshold from -inf to inf, the classification of each group of points in turn goes from 1 to 0 to -1, followed by the next highest group. The `==` operator can be used to compare floats.